# group ordered line numbers

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data that I am trying to group by consecutive values in R. This solution is [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47169195/group-by-consecutive-values-in-r?rq=1) to what I am looking for, however my data is structured like this:

| line_num |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

What I want to do is group each time the number returns to 1 such that I get groups like this:

| line_num | group_num) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |

Any ideas on the best way to accomplish this using dplyr or base R?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `cumsum` on a logical vector

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(group_num = cumsum(line_num == 1))
```

---

or with `base R`

```
df1$group_num <- cumsum(df1$line_num == 1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(line_num = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```